# For statement looping through dictionary in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I need to use a for loop over a dictionary to display all the corresponding values

```
shops = {

              'Starbucks': {
                  'type':'Shops & Restaurants',
                  'location':'Track 19'
               },

              'Supply-Store': {
                   'type':'Services',
                   'location':'Central Station'
               }
         }

for shop in shops:
    print(shop + " is a: " +shop.items(0))
```

What I want my for loop to do is to take one item at a time, and then get the corresponding type and location. Right now, I'm stuck at getting the corresponding types and locations.

Expected Output would be:

```
Starbucks is a Shops & Restaurants located at Track 19.
Supply-Store is a Services located at Central Station.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each value in your `shops` dictionary to be another dictionary with type and location.

What you want might be -

```
for key,value in shops.items():
    print(key + " is a: " + value['type'] + " at : " + value['location'])
```

Comment: I dont know who voted this answer down, but it works. Marked as answered, thanks Sharon!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) passing the dict using `**` to access arguments by name:

```
Shops = {

              'Starbucks': {
                  'type':'Shops & Restaurants',
                  'location':'Track 19'
               },

              'Supply-Store': {
                   'type':'Services',
                   'location':'Central Station'
               }
         }

for shop,v in Shops.items():
    print("{} is a {type} located at {location}".format(shop,**v))
```

Output:

```
Starbucks is a Shops & Restaurants located at  Track 19
Supply-Store is a Services located at  Central Station
```